# Regex expression to match JSON values

Tags: json, regex

I'm curently working on a college project. I'm trying to create a regex expression to return the values from a JSON. Example:

JSON expression: `[{"id": "120","name": "Mary","gender": "feminine"}]`

wished output: `120 Mary feminine`

I tried this solution `\w\b\w+\b(?z!\id|name|gender)`

but without any success.

Comment: Do you want to get the output **specifically** from `"id"`, `"name"` or `"gender"` or just any key whatsoever?

Comment: This is what JSON Parsers are for.

Comment: `[:]\s(\".*\")`?

Comment: my original idea was to select every word "\w" and try to exclude the strings "id", "name", and "gender" from the match

Comment: [:]\s(\".*\") this expression is better than any other that i've came up with but its returning  : "120"; : "Mary"; : "Feminine" and only wish for the raw values

Comment: This is a bad idea unless you know that the JSON is very restricted in its format.

Comment: Put the capture group inside the double quotes if you don't want to include them in the result.

Comment: You could actually be asking something a bit more specific as per @TiberiuZulean. But this question is kind of a meme, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags TL;DR they are different kinds of language in the Chomsky hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const s = '[{"id": "120","name": "Mary","gender": "feminine"}]'
const result = JSON.parse(s).map(x => Object.values(x).join(' '))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: OP is looking for a solution using Regex precisely.